# exim bounce address tag validation

Tags: exim, email-bounces

I ma trying to set up BATV in exim but i am always getting an error:

```
F=<> temporarily rejected RCPT <prvs=1234abcd=my_email@my_domain.ru>: invalid "condition" value "my_email@my_domain.ru"
```

Corresponding ACL:

```
deny message = Invalid reverse path signature
    senders = :
    !condition = ${prvscheck {$local_part@$domain}\
        {\
            ${lookup mysql{SELECT batv FROM virtual_users \
                 WHERE email='${quote_mysql:$prvscheck_address}'}}\
        }\
        {${if eq{$prvscheck_result}{}}}\
    }
```

Exim version 4.72
OS: CentOS 6.3

Really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here correct version:

```
deny message = Invalid reverse path signature
    senders = :
    condition = ${if eq{\
            ${prvscheck {$local_part@$domain}{PRVSCHECK_SQL}{1}}\
            }{}\
            }
    !condition =$prvscheck_resul
```